# Cloning JavaScript with for()

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, cloning

Example is this and this is not working. What is my mistake ?

```
var i=1;
for(i; i <=165; i++){
    jQuery(".tekAlan"+i).click(function() {   
    jQuery(".tekAlan"+i).addClass("tekAlanSecildi");    
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to add to only the clicked item the class. However, it always adds the class to the last one. That's because i is accessed **after** the end of the for, so it always contains 165. Do this to solve your problem:

```
var i=1;
for(i; i <=165; i++){
    jQuery(".tekAlan"+i).click(function() {   
        jQuery(this).addClass("tekAlanSecildi");    
    });
}
```

`jQuery(this)` is a reference of the element affected by the event (in this case, `click`)

Answer (score 6):

You're passing `i` by reference, not by value, so `i` isn't referring to the number that you think it is after your loop runs. Take a look at [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/hXmdG/2/) to see what I mean.

In this case, you can probably just use an attribute selector and `this`:

```
jQuery('[class^="tekAlan"]').click(function() {   
    jQuery(this).addClass("tekAlanSecildi");    
});
```

If you want to fix your current code, you'll have to [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `i` with an anonymous function:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 165; i++){
    (function(i) {
        jQuery(".tekAlan" + i).click(function() {   
            jQuery(".tekAlan" + i).addClass("tekAlanSecildi");    
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Awesome example of shadowing variables. I was also wondering how to solve it without using "this", and your code does the trick.

Comment: are you sure only `.tekAlan165` will be clickable? I think all of them will receive the click event, but, again, all of them will add the class to the last one

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not very clear, you could try something like this

1) add a class to all of your elements

2)

```
$('.someclass').click(function(){

    $(this).addClass('someotherclass');

})
```

you dont need a for loop.

Comment: in my case yes I do :D Thank you for answer.